# FitNesse/Gradle command line output into file

Tags: command-line, gradle, output, fitnesse

I am trying to start FitNesse tests using the command line in Gradle.

**build.gradle**

```
exec {
    ignoreExitValue = true
    commandLine = [
        'java', 
        '-cp',          
        fitnesseClasspath, // fitnesseClasspath set somewhere else
        'fitnesseMain.FitNesseMain',
        '-c',
        "${suite}?suite&format=xml", // suite set somewhere else
    ]

}
```

Now I want the results to be written into a xml file (let's call it output.xml) and not into the command window.
How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

Here you go, just replace the arguments.

```
exec {
    commandLine = ['ls']
    args = [
        "./",
    ]
    standardOutput = new FileOutputStream("./hello.txt")
}
```

Comment: Thank you ! This writes all the command line output into the file. Is there a way just to get the FitNesse results into the file ?

Comment: Where does FitNesse outputs it now? Sorry, I am not familiar with FitNesse